# Share product instantly when added from backend woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello Is there a way to share product instantly when added in backend. I want to show product images in facebook, instagram whenever it is added from backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin 
https://cedcommerce.com/woocommerce-extensions/product-auto-share.
Please see this perhaps it's helpful for you

Comment: this extension doesnot support instagram

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-automatically-publish-from-wordpress-to-instagram  hope this helpful

Comment: thank you @Sanket, it should work for me, let me give a try.

Comment: Sure @user3209130.if my answer will help you then please +1 for the answer is helpful. so i can post my answer direct in comment.